# How to annotate user questions when creating an intent (with SDKs)?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am using the python SDK and trying to annotate entity values automatically when [creating the intents](http://dialogflow-python-client-v2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gapic/v2beta1/types.html#dialogflow_v2beta1.types.Intent.TrainingPhrase.Part) (with user questions in example mode).

For each part object i can annotate any word as a value of an entity manually. but how can i make Dialogflow annotate them automatically.

I thought, if i set the user_defined=False, it would annotate me in auto mode. But, even when i am manually annotating it, user_defined doesn't make a difference if it is True or False.

Answer (score 1):

The automatic annotation is only a feature of the console and not a feature of the API.